# windows phone application crashing after changing current playing song

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, media-player

I'm using `Mediaplayer.Queue` to retrieve information from zune on Windows Phone about currently playing song (artist, song name, etc). Everything is fine, but if I'm changing song from the *fast access menu* (ie. from clicking the volume-buttons) the app crashes.

What do I need to do to prevent this scenario in the future? Also, when the user changes the track, how do I update the current song info?

Comment: When debugging directly on device, which part of the code gives you the exception? Please give us some code, to get some context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable music hub debugging on the device, you need to [connect with WPConnect.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg180729%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) instead of Zune. The guide tells you how.

Once you got debugging running, you should be able to get a full exception and stack-trace. If you post that, we can give you further help, if necessary.